# A Controller plugin defined in application.ini not found by the front controller

Tags: zend-framework, front-controller

I defined a plugin in application.ini directory like

> resources.frontController.plugins.acl = "CMS_Controller_Plugin_Acl"

The namespace `CMS_` is set to be autoloaded in bootstrap.php

```
    $autoLoader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
    $autoLoader -> registerNamespace("CMS_");
```

But, when I lauch the program I am getting this error.

```
Class 'CMS_Controller_Plugin_Acl' not found in xxx\Zend\Application\Resource\Frontcontroller.php on line 117
```

Comment: `/path/to/libray/CMS/Controller/Plugin/Acl.php` as per suggested by the zf reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to register your namespace in your `application.ini` before the plugin.

```
autoloaderNamespaces.CMS = 'CMS'
resources.frontController.plugins.acl = "CMS_Controller_Plugin_Acl"
```